# Prestashop SHOP-EMAIL not updating after migration

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I just migrated my PS 1.7 from one domain to another, everything fine but I really don't how to change the SHOP email so I can get it right in my "contact us" page.

I tried changing it from BackOffice and do BO is showing the correct email
but in my contact page still the old one.

I tried downloading all the database and searching <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> with no success.
I tried downloading the site files and look which in files searching app and couldn't find it/

I even deleted all the cache manually and nothing can't get the right shop email to be shown on contact page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this e-mail in BO Configure->Shop Parameters->Contact->Stores->Shop email. By the way, it is a field `PS_SHOP_EMAIL` in your configuration table in DB.

Comment: yeah i know that i made it that way, and the db PS_SHOP_EMAIL is updating correctly, but even after erasing cache and everything my old email still showin as contact info on contact us page

Comment: Are you sure that your email isn't hardcoded? Try to switch your theme to the default one and check it out. Or just try to find your old email in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can change your phone number by going to configuration of `ps_contactinfo` module.